# Why can't I see datetime fields in rails_admin show view?

Tags: datetime, rails-admin

I'm adding a new model to rails_admin.  The list page displays datetime fields correctly, even without any configuration.  But the detail (show) page for a given object does not display datetimes. How do I configure rails_admin to show datetime fields on the show page?

Model file: alert_recording.rb:

```
class AlertRecording < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :admin_id, :message, :sent_at, :acknowledged_at, :created_at, :updated_at
end
```

Rails_admin initializer file:

```
...
config.included_models = [
  AlertRecording
]

...

config.model AlertRecording do
  field :sent_at, :datetime
  field :acknowledged_at, :datetime
  field :message
  field :user
  field :admin
  field :created_at, :datetime
  field :updated_at, :datetime
  list do; end
  show do; end
end
```

What's the correct way to configure the datetime fields so I see them on the show view?

Comment: I came here wondering why my prod rails admin wasn't showing a new field I had added to a model. That field was showing just fine on localhost. I ended up having to restart Heroku, presumably because the restart during deployment isn't enough since running the db migration happens afterward and doesn't restart the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in there for `sent_at` and `acknowledged_at` should work. Make sure the records you are trying to "show" have dates present for these fields.

For `created_at` and `updated_at`, try [this](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/994):

```
config.model AlertRecording do
  field :created_at
  configure :created_at do
    show
  end
  field :updated_at, :datetime
  configure :updated_at do
    show
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, that's it. I just wish rails_admin wouldn't silently drop any field that's nil...

Comment: That's configurable: `config.compact_show_view = false`

Answer (score 5):

These fields are hidden by default as you can see here:

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/ead1775c48754d6a99c25e4d74494a60aee9b4d1/lib/rails_admin/config.rb#L277

You can overwrite this setting on your config initializer, just open the file `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb` and add this line to it:

`config.default_hidden_fields = []`

or something like this:

`config.default_hidden_fields = [:id, :my_super_top_secret_field]`

That way you doesn't need to do a config to every model in your app ;)

**BUT!!!** This will show these fields in *edit* action, so it's a good idea to hide id, created_at and updated_at in this case.

To do this you can assign a hash on this setting, like so:

```
config.default_hidden_fields = {
  show: [],
  edit: [:id, :created_at, :updated_at]
}
```

And *voilà*, you have what you want. ;)

Comment: You could also straight up do `config.default_hidden_fields[:show] = []`